# curl command not recognized while call from system or popen in c

Tags: c, curl

trying to call cURL from a .exe using both system and popen command, but it shows like "curl not recognized as internal or external command" error. I have put the curl code directly in a .bat file and its working fine. I have written the .exe file in C. The .exe working fine in one of the system but not on others.

working fine when directly called through command prompt or .bat file

```
char second_cmd[128];
char psBuffer[128];

memset(psBuffer, '\0', 128);
memset(second_cmd, '\0', 128);

strcpy(second_cmd, "curl -v -d \"Testing upload#Name=Sarad#CSP=HP 
Laptop#\" -k POST http://example.com/api.php");

if( (pPipe = _popen( second_cmd, "rt" )) == NULL )
exit(1);
memset(psBuffer, '\0', 128);
printf("\n");
while(fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe))
{
printf(psBuffer);
memset(psBuffer, '\0', 128);
}

//ret = system(second_cmd); //not working too.`
```

Comment: Where did you install curl?

Comment: @melpomene its at c:\windows\system32\curl.exe